# Ошибка: 'Индекс находился вне границ массива.'

Tags: c#, массивы, индексы

Вылезла ошибка:

> *Индекс находился вне границ массива*

Перекопал много форумов, так и не нашел в чем причина.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int count = rnd.Next(0, 11);
int[,] a = new int[count,count];

for (int x = 0; x < a.Length; x++)     
    for (int y = 0; y < a.Length; y++) 
    {
        a[x,y] = count; // Заполнение элементов рандомом
    } // Bот тут ошибка!

for (int x = 0; x < a.Length; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < a.Length; y++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a[x,y] +" ");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

[image: собственно сама ошибка]

Comment: На форумах то рыли...а в дебаг режиме запуститься?

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.WriteLine(a.Length); // count*count
for (int x = 0; x < a.GetLength(0); x++)
  for (int y = 0; y < a.GetLength(1); y++)
```